# Google Map Android API V2 - blank screen on release version only

Tags: android, google-maps

What a wierd situation, my app works perfectly on debug mode. When released, I have a blank screen instead of my map.

I've looked for lots of post in stackoverflow. I has rebuild my key, using my keystore signature and debugstore signature (initially I had two google Key, I didn't know that we could have the same API Key with several signatures)

How can I debug something in release mode ?

This is a paradoxe !

Comment: if you are going to sign in your apk you need to make release sha1 key for it.

Comment: ok, found response by myself, would be better if Marcin Orlowski had not treated this question as equal as an other, looks like details is not important to him... well here is a solution : you need to move meta at the bottom of the manifest file (dont ask me why) just before </application>    exemple  : <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />   </application>